# How to print random items from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

everyone. I'm trying to complete a basic assignment. The program should allow a user to type in a phrase. If the phrase contains the word "happy" or "sad", that word should then be randomly replaced by a synonym (stored in a dictionary). The new phrase should then be printed out. What am I doing wrong? Every time I try to run it, the program crashes. This is the error I get:

```
  0_part1.py", line 13, in <module>
    phrase["happy"] = random.choice(thesaurus["happy"])
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import random

thesaurus = {
    "happy": ["glad", "blissful", "ecstatic", "at ease"],
    "sad": ["bleak", "blue", "depressed"]
    }

phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")
phrase2 = phrase.split(' ')


if "happy" in phrase:
    phrase["happy"] = random.choice(thesaurus["happy"])
if "sad" in phrase:
    phrase["sad"] = random.choice(thesaurus["sad"])

print(phrase)
```

Comment: *"the program crashes"* - can you be more specific? Please include the full traceback message. Have you tried searching for that message on e.g. Google?

Comment: Yes, it says "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment". The error is in the line "phrase["happy"] = random.choice(thesaurus["happy"])

Comment: `phrase` is a `str`ing, so e.g. `phrase["happy"] = ...` is **never going to work**, because 1. strings are immutable; and 2. they are sequences, not mappings.

Comment: Just edited it to include the full thing. What do I do instead? I am very new to python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error is that `phrase` is a string, and strings are immutable. On top of that, strings are *sequences*, not *mappings*; you can index them or slice them (e.g., `happy_index = phrase.find("happy"); phrase[happy_index:happy_index+len("happy")]`), but you can't use them like dictionaries.

If you want to create a new string, replacing the substring `happy` with another word, use the `replace` method.

And there's no reason to check first; if `happy` isn't found, `replace` wil do nothing.

So:

```
phrase = phrase.replace("happy", random.choice(thesaurus["happy"]))
```

---

While we're at it, instead of explicitly looking up each key, you may want to *loop* over the dictionary and apply *all* the synonyms:

```
for key, replacements in thesaurus.items():
    phrase = phrase.replace(key, random.choice(replacements))
```

---

Finally, notice that this code will replace all instances of `happy` with the same replacement. Which I think your intended code was also trying to do. If you want to replace each of them with a separately randomly-chosen synonym, that's a bit more complicated. You could loop over `phrase.find("happy", offset)` until it returns `-1`, but a neat trick might make it simpler: `split` the string around each instance of `happy`, substitute in a different synonym for each split part, then `join` them all back together. Like this:

```
parts = phrase.split("happy")
parts[:-1] = [part + random.choice(thesaurus["happy"]) for part in parts[:-1]]
phrase = ''.join(parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number from `(0..[size of list - 1])`. Then, access that index of the list. To get the length of a list, just do `len(list_name)`.

Comment: In order to replace, here is an example.

Comment: string = string.replace(string, [get index value of list here])

Comment: Add your comments to the answer in order to improve it.